# Port bind exception in spring XD if spring_profiles_active environment variable is added

Tags: spring-xd

I am running into a weird issue while trying to run spring XD admin and XD container on single machine. When I don't export the environment variable `spring_profiles_active` XD admin and XD container are working properly as expected but when I add this environment variable xd-container is throwing a port bind exception, Please find the exception stack trace [here](https://gist.github.com/kbeathanabhotla/230dd9460d2695b61a2fa8caad45522e#file-exception-stacktrace-txt).

I can see that xd-container is trying to run some service on 9393, I can definitely change the port and make it run. I would like to understand why am I not facing this issue if I don't export `spring_profiles_active` environment variable.

Please find my container servers.yml file [here](https://gist.github.com/kbeathanabhotla/b8c1093b69632a69837ccd3920a93646#file-xd-container-yml).

Comment: Please do not link to the code and stack trace.  Put the relevant parts of the code/error in with the question.

Comment: What value are setting the exported property to?

Comment: the environment variable exported is `export spring_profiles_active=prod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following on your container environment

```
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,container
```